# Scala sbt does not see (and does not load) dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to connect to `mssql` server. So I described `dependency` in my `build.sbt` file like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.1.0.jre8"
```

Then I started `sbt`. Then I ran `'run'` command and got an error

```
object microsoft is not a member of package com
import com.microsoft.sqlserver
```

Here is full app object:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver

object PC extends App {
  println("Hello there") // yes, I do nothing with microsoft.sqlserver package 
}
```

And this is a content of `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.15
```

After this I googled, found nothing, and went into `/tmp/` dir to emulate what I tried to do in my working dir.
I created `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Hello sbt"

version := "2017-05-31"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.1.0.jre8"
```

and simple app:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver

object HW extends App {
  println("Hello there!")
}
```

and project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.15
```

As you can see it's almost the same as my previous code - only object and file names differ.

This code was compiled and run just fine.

I found `com.microsoft.sqlserver jar` file path in `target/streams/compile/dependencyClasspath/$global/streams/export`: it points at `.ivy2` dir in my home dir: `/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/jars/mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar`. (So it's been loaded.)

I can't understand why two almost absolutely same projects behave differently.

I also cleaned both folders from `sbt` files and got the same result anyway.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Any ideas?

P.S. `show sources` in both dirs shows different locations. I removed `.sbt` dir from my `home` dir, then ran `sbt` again.
Reviewing `project/target/streams/compile/dependencyClasspath/$global/streams/export` and `target/streams/compile/dependencyClasspath/$global/streams/export` showed different results. For some reason at `run` sbt does not look into `~/.ivy2/` dir.

What "solved" my problem was deleting the whole structure of scala code from my project and create it again from the scratch. Seems like `sbt` uses some cache which is hardly related to the directory it was executed from.

Comment: What does `show sources` and `show managedClasspath` output? In either of the cases.

Comment: In *fail*( dir it says:
Attributed(/home/alex/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.6/lib/scala-library.jar)

and in *ok* dir:
Attributed(/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.9.2.jar)
Attributed(/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/jars/mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar)
[and so on]

They point at different places. Why is that?

Comment: Different sbt versions? Also, add `scalaVersion := "2.12.2"`. Apparently it didn't pick up your dependency.

Comment: `Also, add scalaVersion := "2.12.2"` - how will this help?

Comment: Gives you a reasonable scala version to work with ;-)

Comment: `Gives you a reasonable scala version to work with` - but is doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: try to import as `import _root_.com.microsoft.sqlserver`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but after I removed directory dir with scala code completely and created it again from the scratch the problem gone.

It seems there is a hard connection between sbt and the source code location.